# Number Sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Forgive me for the unoriginal title, it's been a while since I made a puzzle.

Just a simple number sequence, find X and give reasoning/pattern

> *1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 61, 5, 52, 6, 63, 7, 94, 8,* **X**

Disclaimer: I did search to see if this was a duplicate, but not very hard. Let me know if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> 46

as the sequence is

> each positive integer followed by the reverse of its square.